# Find Cubic Given Zeroes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, cubics

I was given this question for my Algebra class and am really struggling to find the answer.  The problem:
Given that f(x) is a cubic function with zeros at -7 and 4 i +3 , find an equation for f(x) given that f(-5) = -2.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If $c$ is a zero of $f$, then it must have a factor that is:

$$(x-c)$$

Also realize that you're dealing with imaginary roots, and must consider both $3+4i$ and $3-4i$ (as I'd assume real polynomial coefficients). That leaves you with:

$$f(x) = (x+7)(x-(3+4i))(x-(3-4i)) \times C$$

And solve for $C$ such that $f(-5)=-2$.

Comment: my guess is that the cubic is required to have real coefficients; the non-real roots should be a conjugate pair

Comment: @WillJagy Yeah, I edited my answer once I noticed that.

Comment: Yes all the coefficients have to be real.

Comment: Only if the coefficients are real. If the coefficients can be complex, the conjugate is not necessary to be a root

Comment: Andrew, the conjugate of $3 + 4 i$ is $3 - 4i$  You have typed $-3$

Comment: @WillJagy Gah. Thanks for the heads up, don't know why I was thinking negation.

Comment: You have now typed $4i-3,$ still wrong. If you make mistakes composing on the screen, it might be better to write it down on paper before typing here

Comment: @WillJagy Yeah, writing answers on my phone isn't doing me any good.

Comment: I've also changed the + to $\times$. If you add something, then $f(-7)=C\ne 0$

Comment: @Andrei Thanks for the help and notifying me.